# Pagination.Item kept active all the time, I have no idea why

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, pagination, frontend, react-bootstrap

I currrently using react bootstrap, and I having weird output, this is my Paginate.js

```
import Pagination from 'react-bootstrap/Pagination';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

function Paginate({ pages, page, keyword = '', isAdmin = false }) {
    console.log("paginate_pages:",pages)
    console.log("paginate_page:",page)
    console.log("paginate_keyword:",keyword)
  if (keyword && keyword.includes('?keyword=')) {
    keyword = keyword.split('?keyword=')[1].split('&')[0];
  } else {
    keyword = '';
  }
  console.log("split_keyword:",keyword)
  let current_page=parseInt(page)
  console.log('current_page:',current_page)
  return (
    pages > 1 && (
      <Pagination>
        {[...Array(pages).keys()].map((x) => (  //the output would be [0,1,2], they are integer
          <LinkContainer
            key={x + 1} //example page 1, it will be 1,because x will be 0
            to={
              !isAdmin
                ? {
                    pathname: '/',
                    search: `?keyword=${keyword}&page=${x + 1}`,
                  }
                : {
                    pathname: '/admin/productlist/',
                    search: `?keyword=${keyword}&page=${x + 1}`,
                  }
            }
          >
            <Pagination.Item active={(x + 1) === page >{x+1}</Pagination.Item>
          </LinkContainer>
        ))}
      </Pagination>
    )
  );
}

export default Paginate;
```

My Paginator.Item is active all the time. For example, suppose we are on page 1; in this case, the Paginator.Item for page 1 will be active, right? However, I've noticed that Paginator.Items for pages 2 and 3 are also active at the same time. Is this expected behavior?

[image]
the Paginator.Item page 1,page2 and page 3 are active when I'm in page 1, and I did check my pages and page are integer, help me please

Answer (score 0):

There are Some Changes here

```
<Pagination.Item active={(x + 1) === page >{x+1}</Pagination.Item>
```

Try below Code

```
<Pagination.Item active={x + 1 === current_page}>{x + 1}</Pagination.Item>
```

Maybe It Will Work For You.

Comment: Hi, I paste your code to my project, the Paginator.Item still active automatically, no idea why

Comment: Can you add code where you use this <Pagination > means In Which Component You are Using this <Pagination/>?